# How to convey the turn "to be plus past infinitive" (as in "where C is a constant to be determined")?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, anglais, infinitif, mathématiques

> y=Cx
>
> where C is a constant to be determined.

"where C is a constant to be determined" should be conveyed by

"où C est une constante à déterminer"

or

"où C est une constante à être déterminée"

? Are the two turns equivalent?

In general, the English turn "to be + past infinitive" is always conveyed by "à + infinitive" (or "à + past infinitive"), or are they any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The English turn "to be + past infinitive" is not always conveyed by "à + infinitive" (or "à + past infinitive"); instead the verb "devoir" or "falloir" is used. This is so when this turn conveys the notion of obligation.

- Those toys are to be sold soon, the necessity of it has been made clear to you.

1. Ces jouets doivent être vendus prochainement, la nécessité vous en a été expliquée clairement.
2. Il faut que ces jouets soient vendus prochainement,…

In this context "à vendre" is not right. This form introduces a confusion between "sont mis à la vente" and "doivent être vendus".

To express the mere happening of something planned you use the turn "aller + infinitive".

- This type of cultivation is to be ended in the near future.
  Ce type de culture va être abandonné dans le proche avenir.

One is more likely to use "à + infinitive" for negative uses of the form.

- This recommendation is not to be taken lightly.
  Cette recommandation n'est pas à prendre à la légère.

However, the more idiomatic forms of translation use the verbs "devoir" and "falloir".

- This meat is to be eaten very soon, otherwise it won't be any good.
- Il faut manger cette viande très bientôt, autrement elle ne sera plus bonne.

There is an alternative where the idiomatic turn "c'est" (gallicisme) makes the turn acceptable.

- This vegetable is to be eaten raw.
- C'est un légume à manger cru.
  *or, more current*       Ce légume se mange cru.

Answer (score 2):

"*où C est une constante à déterminer*" is the correct translation.
In general yes, when you say 'to be + past participle' in English in passive voice, the translation will be 'à + infinitif' in French:

- This work is to be done. *Ce travail est à faire.*
- This car is to be repaired. *Cette voiture est à réparer.*
- This is to be corrected. *C'est à corriger.*
- These apples are to be eaten. *Ces pommes sont à manger*

I cannot think of an exception in French, but I can think of some sentences in French that would not be translated with 'to be + past participle':

- We have apples to eat. *Nous avons des pommes à manger*

The difference is that this example is written using active voice ('We/*Nous*' is the subject).

Comment: Ces pommes sont à manger (...au plus vite par exemple) => These apples are to be eaten.

Comment: Indeed, in that case the passive voice is used. I should have used that example as well as a comparison, I'm adding it.